# YouTube Frame API Scripts in local file fail in IE and with Win8 Store app WebView

Tags: javascript, windows-8, webview, youtube, youtube-api

YouTube's IFrame API JS scripts seem not to work when the HTML file is run locally on a system in IE (tried IE 10 and 11). This means the HTML scripts also don't work in a WebView for a Windows 8 Store app.

To verify that I copied the [sample from the YT IFrame API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) into an HTML file and run it locally and also deployed it to my DropBox so it runs online. The YT Frame API scripts in that HTML for the local file are never fired but for the online version.

You can try it yourself. Open the online version: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2681028/Tests/YouTube/yt_test.html then save that file locally to your hard drive and start it from there as well in IE.
The online version runs the YT Frame scripts which make the video start automatically and stop after 6 seconds. The local file does not work that way and never executes the YT Player scripts. When you open the IE Dev Tools and debug you will see that an exception is raised in YT’s JS lib when postMessage is called.

Note, Chrome and  Firefox work just fine with the YT Frame scripts in a local file, so I assume it’s somehow an IE issue!

If that sample runs in a Win 8(.1) Xaml app inside a WebView the same behavior is shown and the debugger breaks at the same postMessage call.

Any ideas how to overcome that and make YT Frame API calls run in a WebView (or local file in IE)?

Comment: Something like this has happened to me recently as well, when I try to embed a YouTube video into a WebView I get an "object doesn't Support this property or method Rd" exception undebugable. But before today this error didn't happen :S